# VS 2015 update issue and sample doesn't run

Tags: uwp

I tried to run Microsoft UWP sample CameraBarcodeScanner but it requests me to update UWP Tools. So I launched this update which results by this screen: (sorry for french language)

[image]

But no other installation is running.

So I restarted my computer and I retried to load the poject with the following issue:

> C:\samuel\github\ms-universal_samples\Samples\CameraBarcodeScanner\cs\CameraBarcodeScanner.csproj : error  : The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.14332.0\XamlCompiler\Microsoft.Windows.UI.Xaml.Common.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the  declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.  C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\WindowsXaml\v14.0\8.21\Microsoft.Windows.UI.Xaml.Common.targets

Thanks for any help

Comment: Did you check your task manager? did you see any WindowsInstaller.exe running?

Comment: No other WindowsInstaller.exe is running. Also I don't know how to retry to install it because now I have no update available for Windwows 10 SDK from the dialog Extensions and updates

Comment: Can you please translate the exceptions into English? I don't know french at all...

Comment: I translated the exception in the post. So for the screenshot the exception is something like: Setup failed. An other installation is in progress. Finish it before performing this installation. Error code: -2147023278

Comment: You might want to try to repair your installation and retry installing the update.